# I'm trying to select a random string to populate individual labels whilst removing the selected one each time

Tags: ios, swift, random

I am trying to reuse a piece of code which works perfectly for multiline `strings` in one of my `published apps` but I can't figure out why it's different and doesn't work for this `project`.

It doesn't seem to be because of the different `labels` or the time delayed action but I could be wrong.

```
    var randomNumberSelection = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomNumberSelection.count)))
    let removed = randomNumberSelection.remove(at: index)
    guard !removed.isEmpty else {
        return
    }
    if label1.text == nil && label2.text == nil && label3.text == nil && label4.text == nil{
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute:{
           self.label1.text = removed

          if self.label1.text != nil && self.label2.text == nil && self.label3.text == nil && self.label4.text == nil{
             DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute:{
                 self.label2.text = removed
             }
          })
       }
   })
```

If I just use the `array` it works well but occasionally `duplicates` and I want to eliminate the possibility of duplicates.

Comment: Explain the problem statement for which you're using this code.

Comment: How big is your array?  Can you just keep track of the random entries you have used so far and check for a duplicate every time you generate a new entry.  If it is a duplicate, generate a new random entry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured out the best simple solution which seems to work perfectly.
Considering if you use .randomElement() you can't then add .removeLast() to the string, this works well and it's simple!

```
var randomNumberSelection = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].shuffled()

if label1.text == nil && label2.text == nil && label3.text == nil && label4.text == nil{
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute:{
       self.label1.text = randomNumberSelection.removeLast()

      if self.label1.text != nil && self.label2.text == nil && self.label3.text == nil && self.label4.text == nil{
         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute:{
             self.label2.text = randomNumberSelection.removeLast()
         })
      }
   })
}
```